# Which Pathfinder classes and archetypes provide benefits for successfully identifying creatures with the Knowledge skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, knowledge-check

I'm looking to make a character who knows everything about everything. To make such a character function, I'd want to truly *benefit* from the knowledge he has. Which class/archetypes benefit the most from successful Knowledge checks?

I'm aware of a few ways to improve the Knowledge rolls, I'm specifically looking for Class Features that use a success to increase the character or his party's capabilities when fighting identified creatures.

For example, the [Investigator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/) can take [Talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/investigator-talents/#TABLE-Investigator-Talents) such as:

[Inspirational Expertise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/investigator-talents/paizo-investigator-talents/inspirational-expertise/)

> When an investigator succeeds at a Knowledge check to identify a monster‘s special powers or vulnerabilities, he can expend one use of inspiration as a swift action to grant allies within 30 feet that can hear him a +4 insight bonus on attack rolls against that monster or type of monster for 1 round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of abilities that grant you bonuses on successful Knowledge checks, but combining them together to really make the most out of that trick would be very difficult. Wanting to focus on party buffing is going to limit you solely to the Investigator talent you've linked in your post.

A shaman with a Lore spirit gains the [Monstrous Insight](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classes/shaman.html#monstrous-insight) spirit ability, granting +2 insight to hit a creature and +2 AC against its attacks for themselves only.

A character can take the [Kirin Style](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#kirin-style) feat chain to gain Intelligence-based bonuses against creatures, but for themselves only.

An inquisitor can take the [Exploit Lore](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/ultimateMagicFeats.html#exploit-lore) feat to gain a +2 bonus on attack and damage rolls against an identified creature, but for themselves only.

If there are third-party feats or archetypes that do what you're looking for, I am not aware of them.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the benefits were few and far between, I just wanted another set of eyes on it, as the saying goes. I was also looking for self-buffs, as you listed, the party bonus was just the one I knew of off the top of my head.